# Is there an iOS equivalent of Bonjour for Mac?

Tags: ios, network, safari, bonjour

you know how you can search your locally networked devices on Bonjour in Safari on Macs, and once you select a device, Safari asks you to log in with a username and password to get to the device's settings?

Well i was wondering if I can do the same thing on an iPhone or iPad. Since there is no official Bonjour on iOS, is there a third party app or something that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact, Bonjour on iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Fing is what you're looking for, you can see who is connected and all the info but Im pretty shure you cant connect to the devices, just as in a PC, Mac, etc...

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overlook-fing/id430921107

Hope it Helps.